# How to make a user be able to see and change the info on their account?

Tags: php, forms, account, display

How would you make it so that a user is able to check their account information that is saved in the database and edit it? Let's say a user clicks on their account info page, it would display something like:

> Username [abc]
>
> Email: [aba@aba.abc]
>
> Age: [20]
>
> [Save Button]

When the user loads up the page, they would be able to see their information for those specified fields from the database. However, all this information would be in editable field that could be re-typed and saved.

So how would I go about doing this? What would this look like in PHP? I do not know how to display data from the databse onto a page, and I would imagine I would ned to do that. Also, does this data (that is being displayed on the page) need to be sanitized like how it was when the account was created?

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials on the internet for this. It just takes a little bit of googling.

Comment: Honestly couldn't find any. Any you found in particular you would like to share?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-stickies-167/program-basic-secure-login-system-using-php-mysql-891201.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this and unless necessary theres no need to reinvent the wheel.

A good place to start would be looking at the many open source projects that are out there such as:

- UserFrosting - Modern user management for PHP @http://www.userfrosting.com
- PHP Login @http://www.php-login.net

Alternativley frameworks such as Laravel, Yii2 and Symfony are a good environment to build these sort of systems in.  With Laravel for example almost everything is configured for you out of the box. The authentication configuration file is located at config/auth.php, which contains several well documented options for tweaking the behavior of the authentication services.

After looking at these if you did decide you wanted to start from the ground up with your own design then there are many good in depth tutorials freely available online such as http://www.ineedtutorials.com/code/php/complete-advanced-login-member-system-php-tutorial

I hope my reply helps.

Comment: Thanks, i will check all of those out!